# How to format alert/notification in REDCap to send for each instance of specific form during a data import?

Tags: redcap

**What I need :**
When i import data into a project for a repeating form, i need a notification to trigger based off logic in that form. I need this to repeat for each new instance of that form.

**What is wrong?**
Currently the notification only triggers on manual data entry and not during import.
Also, notfication only triggers once OR triggers everytime ANY repeating form is saved.

**What i've tried**
My data import works fine.
Ive tried setting te notification to be triggered from survey saved and ive tried it to be triggered on data import.
I've tried including smart variable [last-instance] on my trigger logic, and without.
Ive tried setting to trigger only once per record AND trigger once per record and for every instance.

Comment: Consider asking your institution's REDCap admin to post this question on the "REDCap Community website".